# MySQL in C#: how do I enable the traffic compression?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

It may seem unbelievable but it's the first time this question is asked.

Both Devart and Oracle MySQL connectors for .NET [supports the compression](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/ComparingProviders.html). But how can I enable the compression?

I've tried to look thoroughly in the MySQLConnection properties but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Try adding `Compress=true` in the connection string, lifted from [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dotconnect-for-mysql/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/, add `Compress=True;` to your connection string, or set `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.UseCompression = true;`.

Comment: yesterday I could find only the first solution, so really thanks for the second.